# Transformer section and magnetic field

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism

I have a magnetic core. I excite it with a current I, the magnetizing force is approximately equal to :

$$ H = {NI \over l_{c}} $$

Where N is the number of turn and l_c is the mean path length of the core.

And the flux density B is equal to :

$$ B = {µH} $$ where µ is the permeability of the core.

Whatever the section of the core, the flux density will always be the same...

If I take the approximate formula of the inductance, it can be shown that the flux density is equal from the previous equation :

$$ B = {L \Delta I \over NS} $$ where S is the section of the core and L is the inductance. L is proportional to S. So according to this formula, the flux density does not depends on the section

Finally, according to the electrical formula of an inductance :
$$ L \Delta I  = V \Delta T $$

Then B is equal to :
$$ B = {V \Delta T \over NS} $$

And it seems to depends on S ... But this is not what the first formula shows... Does the flux density depend on the section of the core or not ?

Have a nice day !

Comment: Helo! The formula H=NI/lc is used for CTs, for example, and other 'current-excited' devices,  where the magnetic flux that will circulate in the core depends on the reluctance of the magnetic path. In a transformer (which is excited by voltage) the flux that will circulate through the core does not depend on the magnetic path (infinite permeability), but on the voltage imposed on the primary winding. Using Phi(t)=1/N*integral(U(t),t). Undoubtedly, the magnetic flux density B depends on the core cross section, just as the current density on a conductor depends on the conductor cross section.

Comment: Jess, whenever you are using anything other than an air-core inductor (which doesn't have a \$B_\text{MAX}\$), you must find a core material with \$B_\text{MAX}\$ that's greater than the Webers (volt-seconds) divided by the product of the cross-section area (\$A_\text{C}\$) and N, just as you show. You can also put together the magnetic path length to find the required volume, as well, for a given peak magnetic energy. Have a crack at that, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger section increases the core's permeance, and thus the inductance of the coil on the core.

It is not visible in your first formula, because this relation apears only in the second formula - the permeability. This quantity depends on the permeance, and thus on the core section.

> Whatever the section of the core, the flux density will always be the same...

Nope, because the permeability in Eq. 2 will change when the section changes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)